# In PSQL, is it possible to insert rows in two different tables with not-nullable foreign key columns referencing each other?

Tags: postgresql

I want to insert a row into two tables that reference each other using not-nullable foreign key columns.

Let's say I have table A named *make*

- `make_id, bigint, (NOT NULL)`
- `name, text`
- `first_model_id, bigint, (NOT NULL)` references `model.model_id`

And a table B named *model*

- `model_id, (NOT NULL)`
- `name, text`
- `make_id, (NOT NULL)` references `make.make_id`

Is it possible within a transaction to insert a row into both of these tables, even though each of the rows does not exist? This is easily doable by making one of the columns `NULL`, inserting the first row, referencing it on the second insert, then getting the new row ID from the second insert.

I'm wondering if this is possible with columns that are `NOT NULL`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming the primary key columns are defined as `serial` (or `bigserial`) you can first get the new IDs using `nextval()` and then use them in the subsequent inserts.

This can either be done separate statements:

```
select nextval(pg_get_serial_sequence('make','make_id'));
select nextval(pg_get_serial_sequence('model','model_id'));

insert into make 
  (make_id, name, first_model_id) 
values (
  currval(nextval(pg_get_serial_sequence('make','make_id'))), 
  'Make One', 
  currval(pg_get_serial_sequence('model','model_id'))
);

insert into model
  (model_id, name, make_id)
values (
  currval(pg_get_serial_sequence('model','model_id')),
  'Make One', 
  currval(nextval(pg_get_serial_sequence('make','make_id')))
);
```

or a single statement using a [data modifying CTE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-with.html#QUERIES-WITH-MODIFYING)

```
with new_ids as (
   select nextval(pg_get_serial_sequence('make','make_id')) as new_make_id, 
          nextval(pg_get_serial_sequence('model','model_id')) as new_model_id 
), new_make as (
  insert into make (make_id, name, first_model_id) 
  select new_make_id, 'Make One', new_model_id
  from new_ids
)
insert into model (model_id, name, make_id) 
  select new_model_id, 'Model 1', new_make_id
from new_ids;
```